# How can I add a dropdown inside a search bar with Ant Design?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, antd

As a part of the project I'm building, I need to add two drop boxes inside the search box. Following the documentation (https://ant.design/components/input) , I had added the `addonAfter` prop to the Input dev, but by doing so the css is getting overrided, and I couldn't configure the dropboxes by setting class name either. Here is my code :

```
const selectAfter = (
    <div className='drop-down'>
      <Select  defaultValue=".com">
        <Option value=".com">.com</Option>
        <Option value=".jp">.jp</Option>
        <Option value=".cn">.cn</Option>
        <Option value=".org">.org</Option>
      </Select>
      <Select defaultValue=".com">
        <Option value=".com">.com</Option>
        <Option value=".jp">.jp</Option>
        <Option value=".cn">.cn</Option>
        <Option value=".org">.org</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );



const SearchField : React.FC<IInputFieldProps> = (props) => (
  
  <Input className="input-field" {...props} addonAfter={selectAfter} />
);
```

CSS :

```
.input-field {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2.3em;
}
```

The issue is, the search box defaults back to how it looks like in the documentation, as I can find no way to add the css.

Please help

Comment: I tired the code in a forked official [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djwf1t?file=demo.tsx) from `antd` but both classes seem to be applying?

Comment: The input is being styled in the sense that the `span` element has the class. This is because AntD's `Input` component is actually a `span` element with a nested `input`. If you're looking to apply the style to the `input` element, you might have to apply styling to the `ant-input` class, which looks like the class given to the `input` element.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Got it, now how do I style the `Select`? ant-Select isn't working

Answer (score 0):

if you mean as in the image

[image]

You can modify it using Popover

```
const { Option } = Select;
const selectAfter = (
<>
<Popover
  content={
    <>
      <Space direction="vertical"  style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Select defaultValue=".com" style={{width: "100%"}}>
          <Option value=".com">.com</Option>
          <Option value=".jp">.jp</Option>
          <Option value=".cn">.cn</Option>
          <Option value=".org">.org</Option>
        </Select>
        <Select defaultValue=".com" style={{width: "100%"}}>
          <Option value=".com">.com</Option>
          <Option value=".jp">.jp</Option>
          <Option value=".cn">.cn</Option>
          <Option value=".org">.org</Option>
        </Select>
      </Space>
    </>
  }
  trigger="click"
>
  <a>Click me <DownOutlined /></a>
</Popover>
 </>
);
const App: React.FC = () => (
<Input
  addonAfter={selectAfter}
/>
);
```